# One dimensional noetherian domain

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, noetherian

Let $(R,m)$ be a one-dimensional Noetherian domain. Is $R$ a *regular* or a topical ring like *Gorenstein* or other kinds?

Answer (score 2):

It is a Cohen Macaulay ring; since every none-zero element is a none-zerodivisor and therefore $depth\ R =1$.
If in addition $R$ be a *PID* then it will be  *regular*, and so *Complete intersection* and *Gorenstein*